# Infragistics.Excel 8.2 How to get the text value from a cell that has a formula

Tags: infragistics

I'm simply trying to read in a spreadsheet, and build a list of objects from the values in the cells.

Two of the cells have formulas applied, how can I read the calculated value instead of the formula.

I'm using Infragistics2.Excel.v8.2, I have seen an example using GetText() from the Infragistics2.Documents.Excel namespace, but I do not seem to have that available, is there another way, if not where can I download the additional dll?

Here is my code, origincountry and destinationcountry are using a formula.

```
foreach (var row in worksheet.Rows)
            {

                var fullScheduleUtc = new FullScheduleUtc
                                          {
                                              Title = "",
                                              Carrier = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                                              FlightNumber = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                                              DepartureStation = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                                              OriginCountry = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
                                              DepartureTime = new TimeSpan(),
                                              DestinationStation = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
                                              DestinationCountry = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
                                              ArrivalTime = new TimeSpan(),
                                              EffectivePeriod = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString(),
                                              Monday = true,
                                              Tuesday = false,
                                              Wednesday = true,
                                              Thursday = true,
                                              Friday = true,
                                              Saturday = true,
                                              AircraftType = row.Cells[10].Value.ToString()
                                          };

                fullScheduleList.Add(fullScheduleUtc);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetAdvantage 2008 Volume 3 changed the behavior so that GetValue will return the value rather than the formula so you would need to upgrade to NetAdvantage 2008 Volume 3 or later.